# Debugging cancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I'm trying to debug the following block.

```
  can :create, Todo do |todo|
    todo.user.account == user.account
  end
```

I'm using `load_and_authorize_resource` at the top of `TodosController`.

**The problem I'm having** is that the 'account' is a nil method for the above `todo.user.account` when performing the :create action. It seems the todo object isn't fully instantiated when it's passed; I'm not sure how to control this bit.

Here are the relevant sections of the TodosController:

```
  def new
    #@todo = Todo.new
    @todo = current_user.todos.build
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @todo }
    end
  end

  def create
    #@todo = Todo.new(params[:todo])

    #Build the @todo object including the relations of who's made this todo.
    @todo = current_user.todos.build(params[:todo])
    @todo.subscriptions.build(:user => current_user, :todo => @todo)
    @todo.subscriptions.build(:user => @todo.assignee, :todo => @todo)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @todo.save
        #format.html { redirect_to @todo, :notice => 'Todo was successfully created.' }
        Notifier.notify_assignee(@todo,current_user).deliver
        format.html { redirect_to :back }
        format.json { render :json => @todo, :status => :created, :location => @todo }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.json { render :json => @todo.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
load_and_authorize_resource :except => :create
```

and then:

```
def create
  #@todo = Todo.new(params[:todo])

  #Build the @todo object including the relations of who's made this todo.
  @todo = current_user.todos.build(params[:todo])
  authorize! :create, @todo
```